# How do I use the same aesthetic mapping across geometric functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several geometric functions, specifically `geom_point` and `geom_abline`. I want some of them to have the same color by mapping the `color` aesthetic to custom values (that are not defined by a column in the dataframe).

In the example below, I want the lines to have to the same color as the surrounding points (without setting `color='red'` outside of `aes()` or adding a grouping column to the original data).

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=wt, color='wt')) +
  geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=qsec, color='qsec')) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=0.01, aes(color='wt')) +
  geom_abline(intercept=20, slope=-0.01, aes(color='qsec'))
```

[image: example_mapping_color_across_geoms]
How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe reshape your data: `mtcars %>% select(disp,wt,qsec)%>%gather(var,val,-disp)%>%ggplot(aes(disp,val,color=var))+geom_point()+geom_abline(aes(intercept=i,slope=s,color=var),data.frame(i=c(0,20),s=c(0.01,-0.01),var=c("wt","qsec"), stringsAsFactors = F), show.legend = F)
`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1558)

The way to do this is

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=wt, color='wt')) +
  geom_point(aes(x=disp, y=qsec, color='qsec')) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=b, slope=m, color='wt'), data.frame(b=0, m=0.01)) + 
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=b, slope=m, color='qsec'), data.frame(b=20, m=-0.01))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! Since the issue seems to be specific for `geom_abline` I have edited my question to mention it, so that the issue is more easily discovarable for others.